# Computation of the trace of a convolution operator

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I try to understand a particular step on page two from the research paper "A multidimensional analog of a limit theorem of G. Szegö".
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/IM1975v009n06ABEH001523/meta

Problem Description:

Let $k\in \mathbb{Z}^m$ and $F(\lambda)\geq0$ $(\lambda \in [0,2\pi]^m)$ be a real function summable on $[0,2\pi]^m$ with Fourier coefficients
$$
R(k) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^m} \int_{[0,2\pi]^m} e^{-i\sum_{j=1}^m k_j\lambda_j} F(\lambda)d\lambda.
$$

Let G be a bounded finitely connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with 2-smooth boundary $\partial G$ each connected component of which has positive Gaussian curvature. Let $T\in(0,\infty)$; let $G_T$ be the domain consisting of all the points Tx for x in G and $v_T$ the number of elements in $G'_T=G_T \cap\mathbb{Z}^m$.

Let $R_T$ be a convolution operator acting on the space $Y_T$ of all finite functions on $G'_T$, taking the function $\Psi(k)$, $k \in G'_T$, to the function
$$
(R_T \Psi)(k)= \sum_{l\in G'_T}R(k-l)\Psi(l).
$$

Problem: Computation of the trace of $R_T^n$.

Solution: Let $q=(k^1,...,k^n)$, $k^j \in \mathbb{Z}^m$. We define the function
$$
H(q)=R(k^1-k^2)R(k^2-k^3)...R(k^n-k^1).
$$
We introduce the subset $U_T=\{ G'_T \times (\mathbb{Z}^m)^{n-1}\} \setminus (G'_T)^n$ $\in (\mathbb{Z}^m)^n$ and the quantity $B_n(T)=\sum_{q\in U_T} H(q)$. Then
$$
\text{trace} R_T^n= v_T S^{*n}(0)-B_n(T),
$$
where * stands for the for operation of conjugation.

Question: My question is very simple how do I get  to the solution.

I would be very pleased about any suggestions or tips for the solution.